# Cannot find module '@fullcalendar/interaction' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Why the error crashes
Cannot find module '@fullcalendar/interaction' or its corresponding type declarations.

although this package is definitely in node modules, it is in yarn.lock and in package json. What's wrong?

```
ERROR in apps/frontend/src/app/app.module.ts:19:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@fullcalendar/interaction' or its corresponding type declarations.

19 import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/vdom.d.ts:1:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'preact' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import * as preact from 'preact';
```

[image: interaction]

[image: preact]

in package json

```
"@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.11.2",
"@fullcalendar/core": "5.11.3",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "5.11.3",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "5.11.3",
"@fullcalendar/list": "5.11.3",
"@fullcalendar/timegrid": "5.11.3",
```

angular 12v

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install also the other modules:

```
npm install @fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/list @fullcalendar/timegrid @fullcalendar/interaction
```